# Ubuntu server 16.04 static and private ip

Tags: networking, server, ip, static-ip, gateway

I have tried a few different combinations in `/etc/network/interfaces`

I'm wanting to add a public ip and a private to my server but it's not wanting to accept both

```
iface eno1 inet static
  address 10.0.0.3
  netmask 255.255.254.0

iface eno1 inet static
  address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  netmask 255.255.255.224
  gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.1

  up route add -net 10.0.0.0/23 gw 10.0.0.1 dev eno1

sudo ifconfig eno1 down && sudo ifconfig eno1 up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was with not being able to restart the network adapter.
after rebooting the pc it works fine with

```
iface eno1 inet static
  address 10.0.0.3
  netmask 255.255.254.0



iface eno1 inet static
  address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  netmask 255.255.255.224
  gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.1
```